# Системы счисления c++

Tags: c++

Каким образом десятичные числа переводятся в 16-ричные и 8-ричные с помощью флагов форматирования `hex` и `oct` или они хранятся в нескольких формах? + как определить, какая система используется для представления отрицательных 16-ричных и 8-ричных чисел?

Comment: все числа хранятся в двоичной системе счисления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Числа хранятся в двоичном виде, в виде наборов битов.

При выводе просто выполняется расчет, как именно выводить эти числа. Ну, грубо говоря, как вывести в восьмеричном виде 12? Остаток от деления на 8 - 4, значит, записываем в младший разряд 4; делим - получаем 1. Очередная итерация: остаток от деления на 8 - 1(следующая цифра), деление дает 0. Значит, в восьмеричной записи это 14...

Что касается отрицательных чисел - то, насколько я помню стандарт, при вводе и выводе в шестнадцатеричном и восьмеричном формате числа приводятся к беззнаковому типу, так что  говорить о знаке не приходится. Если вы имеете в виду бинарный формат - то стандарт, насколько я помню же, таковой не определяет, но обычно используется дополнение до двойки.

Comment: Т.е. сначала из двоичной переводит в 10-чную, а потом делит на 8,16 ? Почему сразу нельзя перевести?

Comment: @vitya312 Естественно, все эти действия выполняются в бинарном представлении. Я просто описал принцип на примере.

Comment: Так с 2-чной в 16- и 8-ричную переводится же просто заменой 4 и 3 цифр соответственно на цифры этих систем

Comment: @vitya312 У меня ощущение, что мы говорим о разных вещах. Еще раз - что именно вам непонятно? А что такое выделение 3 (4) битов как не операция остатка от деления на 8 (16), а их отбрасывание - операция деления на 8 (16)?

Comment: Ну вот допустим у нас есть число -80, которые мы хотим вывести в 16-ричной системе счисления. В системе дополнение до 2 оно представляется в памяти в виде `0110000`. И как из этого числа получается `FFFFFFB0` ?

Comment: @vitya312 Вообще-то int - это **обычно** 32 бита, так что -80 в виде int имеет битовое представление 11111111111111111111111110110000... 0110000 - это 48. См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%29#C.2FC.2B.2B